# Yii2: Finding file and getting path in a directory tree

Tags: yii2, helper, file-find

I'm trying to search for a single filename in a bunch of directories and returning its path. I thought `FileHelper::findFiles()` would be a helping hand but it seems it doesn't accept a filename to search for but just a particular root directory and then it returns an array of found filenames.

Anyone who knows another Yii2 helper to accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look into the documentation. The second argument controls what [findFiles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper.html#findFiles%28%29-detail) will return (which file paths the returned array will contain). You have different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply try:

```
$files = yii\helpers\FileHelper::findFiles('/path', [
    'only' => ['filename.ext'],
    'recursive' => true,
]);
```

Read more [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper.html#findFiles()-detail).

Comment: Thank you! It works that way. `recursive` is not needed though as it is true by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easy on "pure" PHP

```
/**
 * @var $file SplFileInfo
 */
$path = '/path';
$dirIter = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dirIter, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile() === true && $file->getFilename() === '.htaccess') {
        var_dump($file->getPathname());
    }
}
```